# I run across a landscape. What Am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I run across a landscape
>   Of a soft and changing terrain
>   Rarely twice the same shape
>   I am unchanged by the rain
>
> Some know me short,
>   Some know me long,
>   Some see me only in port
>   For some I don't belong
>
> The older you get, the longer you live
>   The more likely it is to meet me
>   And the gift you receive I always give
>   A moment in time saved for memory

**What am I?**

Comment: C'mon, I've figured it out just from the title ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you

> a scar?

I run across a landscape
Of a soft and changing terrain

> Your skin

Rarely twice the same shape

> Every scar is unique

I am unchanged by the rain

> Unlike some other personal features like hairstyle.

Some know me short,
Some know me long,

> Scars can be long or short.  Or, talking about time, the trauma that causes them could be fatal (i.e. known only for a short time).

Some see me only in port

> Not sure

For some I don't belong

> Some people accept their scars in their self image, others feel marred by them.

The older you get, the longer you live
The more likely it is to meet me

> Scars are the result of life experiences

And the gift you receive I always give
A moment in time saved for memory

> Scars are a reminder of a certain event, like a trauma, a child birth, an operation, etc!

Comment: Nice job, My expected answer...

Comment: The answer on "some see me only in port" is pirates have scars?

Answer (score 12):

Are you:

> The Horizon

I run across a landscape
Of a soft and changing terrain

> The horizon is across each landscape and changes if you turn your head from left to right.

Rarely twice the same shape
I am unchanged by the rain

> However you look, you'll never see the exact same horizon. Rain doesn't change the look of the horizon

Some know me short,
Some know me long,

> Horizon' refers to the length of time involved in the investor's strategy for keeping his money in play. An investor with a short horizon wishes to invest his money for only a relatively short time.

Some see me only in port
For some I don't belong

> TCP/IP ports are open on a VMware Horizon View Virtual Desktop

The older you get, the longer you live
The more likely it is to meet me

> Expand your own horizon to live longer.
>  [BBC Program](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b01lxyzc)

And the gift you receive I always give
A moment in time saved for memory

> Beautiful horizon. (Pictures people take, sunset for example across the horizon )

Comment: I think the seeing in port part refers to people living in port-side cities where high-rise buildings occlude the horizon, so they only see it when at the beach.

Comment: "TCP/IP ports are open on a VMware Horizon View Virtual Desktop"... nice.

Answer (score 7):

Different kind of answer this time:

> you are a CHILD.

*I run across a landscape*
*Of a soft and changing terrain*

> Children running across the grass.

*Rarely twice the same shape*

> Children grow and change as they get older.

*I am unchanged by the rain*

> Children are willing to play in the rain as well as the sun.

*Some know me short,*
*Some know me long,*

> People might know a child either when they're young or when they're older and taller.

*Some see me only in port*

> A parent who's a sailor might only get to see their child when their ship is in port.

*For some I don't belong*

> Some people don't want to have children.

*The older you get, the longer you live*
*The more likely it is to meet me*

> Older people are more likely to have children.

*And the gift you receive I always give*
*A moment in time saved for memory*

> Having children gives you precious memories to save up.

Comment: This is probably it

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil The last four lines were what put this into my mind: it seems to fit those better than any of the other answers here, even though it's not quite such a good fit for some of the earlier lines.

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

> Cloud

I run across a landscape

> On the sky

Of a soft and changing terrain

Rarely twice the same shape

> nearly imposible two clouds with the same exact shape

I am unchanged by the rain

> Clouds are above rain

Some know me short,

Some know me long,

Some see me only in port

> There are a lot of possibilities

For some I don't belong

> When you want to get a tan

The older you get, the longer you live

The more likely it is to meet me

> Rarely nobody dies without have seen a cloud in their lifes

And the gift you receive I always give

> rain, makes the plants grow

A moment in time saved for memory

Comment: You didn't answer or forgot to answer for the last line.

Comment: @TheBitByte yeah ... I'm thinking about it. not sure yet

Comment: Also, you said "*rarely nobody dies without seeing a cloud*, but I disagree. Some people may die indoors, in places with no windows perhaps, and thus cannot see any clouds.

Comment: I meant, in their lifes, not at the dying moment

Comment: So, did you intend to mean like "*the older you get, the more clouds you might see*"? This is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 2):

You are:

> a sea tide or sea waves

I run across a landscape,
Of a soft and changing terrain

> A tide passes over the beach

Rarely twice the same shape

> The shape of each tide is different. There are least chances that two tides have same shape.

I am unchanged by the rain

> Rain cannot effect tides.

Some know me short,
Some know me long

> Some tides are short and some are long

Some see me only in port

> Sometimes tides occur at ports

For some I don't belong

> Tides have no relationship with one another

The older you get, the longer you live

> Long tides travels several miles

The more likely it is to meet me

> We are eager to swim in tides

And the gift you receive I always give

> enjoyment

A moment in time saved for memory

> A picture of beach with tides

Answer (score 2):

I think you are:

> A wave

I run across a landscape
Of a soft and changing terrain
Rarely twice the same shape
I am unchanged by the rain

> The first verse can refer to the ocean or large body of water.
>  Waves run across them, and rain cannot change them.

Some know me short,
Some know me long,
Some see me only in port
For some I don't belong

> Radio waves - some are short, some are long.
>  Some people only see ocean waves when visiting a port.
>  Not sure about the don't belong, but I'm guessing microwaves or cellphone radio which some people think is detrimental to health.

The older you get, the longer you live
The more likely it is to meet me
And the gift you receive I always give
A moment in time saved for memory

> Humans wave to each other, usually to say goodbye.
>  The longer you live, the more often you wave to someone
>  This is a moment in time, often savoured with a tinge of sadness.
>  The gift is the memory of a visit coming to an end. (e.g.: Remembering waving goodbye the last time you saw a grandparent before they died.)

Comment: Similar to [this previous answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/43270/5373).

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be

> sunlight

I run across a landscape

> Sunlight spreading from the horizon across the land

Of a soft and changing terrain
Rarely twice the same shape

> it is changed by the clouds and hills

I am unchanged by the rain

> Rain doesn't wash it away

Some know me short,
Some know me long,

> different lengths

Some see me in only in port
For some I don't belong

> walls would block sunlight

The older you get, the longer you live
The more likely it is to meet me

> more chance of seeing it

And the gift you receive I always give
A moment in time saved for memory

> it is a beautiful sight

Comment: Good guess, but not it!

Comment: @rsp If this is not it, then your riddle could potentially be too broad. Please edit it to ensure only a single answer is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're:

> The shoreline or waterline

I run across a landscape
Of a soft and changing terrain

> Beaches are usually soft and often change quite rapidly

Rarely twice the same shape

> but random chance means it's always different

I am unchanged by the rain

> but changed by the tides, this also gives the water theme while excluding rivers and lakes which are changed by the rain

Some know me short,
Some know me long,

> If you live on a small island there's not much shoreline or you could be looking at miles of golden sands.

Some see me only in port

> You will see the shoreline in port, some will only see the sea there, some will only see the land there if they live at sea.

For some I don't belong

> some people never see the sea

The older you get, the longer you live
The more likely it is to meet me

> but most people eventually do

And the gift you receive I always give
A moment in time saved for memory

> Who doesn't remember a day out at the seaside

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Rivers

I run across a landscape
Of a soft and changing terrain

> Old rivers fill their valleys with soft and changing alluvial sediments; the Delmarva peninsula is an example of such terrain

Rarely twice the same shape

> I can spend hours looking at the ancient riverbed swirls, meanders and oxbows of river courses.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxbow_lake#/media/File%3ASonghuaRiver_ASTER_20020401.jpg

I am unchanged by rain

> When it rains the river is just as wet, though this is my weakest clue since rain can swell and flood a river, changing it

Some know me short,
Some know me long,

> Rivers come in all sizes

Some see me only in port

> River mouths are natural harbors.  The biggest ports in the world are on rivers: Rotterdam and the Rhine, NYC and the Hudson, Shanghai and the Yangtze

For some I don't belong

> Dams can divert or stop a river flow.  Floods are unwanted.

The older you get, the longer you live
The more likely it is to meet me

> Older rivers tend to be broader and cut water gaps or capture tributaries making them larger features on the terrain, more likely to be encountered

And the gift you receive I always give
A moment in time saved for memory

> Alluvial deposits capture fossils in sedimentary layers.  This is how shales and mudrocks form https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudrock

Answer (score 0):

I started from the end.

```
The older you get, the longer you live
The more likely it is to meet me
```

> the older yoou are the more likely it is to meet death

```
And the gift you receive I always give
```

> everyone has to die, so everyone gets teh gift of death

```
A moment in time saved for memory
```

> if you die your death is memorized

```
Some know me short,
Some know me long,
```

> there are multiple ways to die, some take some time, some are suddenly

```
Some see me only in port
```

> there are people, who fear the death in special places (port may be home, maybe the port to the world)

```
For some I don't belong
```

> there are people who ignore teh existance of death

```
I run across a landscape
Of a soft and changing terrain
```

> death is everywhere and everytime, but so the times change the world

```
Rarely twice the same shape
```

> everyone has his individual death

```
I am unchanged by the rain
```

> death comes at sunshine or rain

Answer (score 0):

I think it is.

> Alcohol

I run across a landscape

> Grape, barley, hops and such

Of a soft and changing terrain

> Different alcohol requires different environments

Rarely twice the same shape

> Comes in a variety of formats

I am unchanged by the rain

> Water does not break down alcohol

Some know me short,

> Shortz, shots

Some know me long,

> Long island ice tea

Some see me only in port

> Port Wine

For some I don't belong

> People who don't drink

The older you get, the longer you live
The more likely it is to meet me

> There is a drinking age limit

And the gift you receive I always give
A moment in time saved for memory

> Memories of a good time? hmmmmm

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> A house/the concept of home?

I run across a landscape
Of a soft and changing terrain

> Houses/homes can be built just about anywhere. Neighborhoods tend to "run across a landscape".

Rarely twice the same shape

> Everyone's house is unique in some way, whether it's the overall shape or the furniture/people within.

I am unchanged by the rain

> Houses are built to withstand the rain.

Some know me short,
Some know me long,

> Some people bounce from home to home. Others stay in the same place for generations.

Some see me only in port

> Sailors who don't consider a ship their "home" would only see their home/house in port.

For some I don't belong

> By choice (i.e. nomads) or circumstance, some people don't have a home.

The older you get, the longer you live
The more likely it is to meet me

> You're more likely to establish a home as you get older, often for financial reasons.

And the gift you receive I always give

> The comfort given by a nice home.

A moment in time saved for memory

> Homes are where most people will make a majority of their memories.

I lost faith in this answer as I was writing it, but I'm committed at this point.